# Is Schur’s lemma always true for smooth irreducible representations of locally compact subgroup?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

In the book “The Local Langlands Conjecture for GL(2)” by Bushnell and Henniart, they prove the Schur’s lemma for groups G that G/K is countable where K is any open compact subgroup. Is Schur’s lemma valid for general groups? Are there counter examples?

Comment: There is certainly a version of Schur's lemma that is true for **strongly continuous** unitary irreps of arbitrary locally compact groups - does that sound like what you are after? Or do you want irreps that might not be unitary, such as SL(2,R) acting on R^2?

Comment: Sorry，I made mistake in my title,I mean smooth irreducible representations of locally profinite groups.

Comment: Let $G = \mathbf{C}(t)^{\times}$ with the discrete topology.  This is trivially a locally compact and locally profinite group with no reasonable countability property, and it acts on the $\mathbf{C}$-vector space $V = \mathbf{C}(t)$ by the evident scaling irreducibly but violates Schur's Lemma over $\mathbf{C}$. This (counter)example comes from considering the way countability is used in the proof of the result you mention.

Comment: Yes, it is even locally profinite with discrete topology. Thanks!

Comment: @nfdc23, would you be willing to post that as an answer, so that this problem doesn't show up as unanswered?

Comment: @LSpice: I prefer not to do so (not enough "meat" in it), but anyone else is welcome to do it (I don't care about "points" and such stuff, as you know).  I'm not sure why it matters if something shows up as unanswered or not.

Comment: @nfdc23 Mainly because some people click on and read unanswered questions, hoping to answer them, and are then disappointed when there is nothing left to do. Also I believe the system bumps unanswered questions to the front page occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

@nfdc23's [counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284218/is-schur-s-lemma-always-true-for-smooth-irreducible-representations-of-locally-c/284289#comment701833_284218) (posted as CW to avoid reputation):

> Let $G=\mathbb C(t)^\times$ with the discrete topology. This is trivially a locally compact and locally profinite group with no reasonable countability property, and it acts on the $\mathbb C$-vector space $V=\mathbb C(t)$ by the evident scaling irreducibly but violates Schur's Lemma over $\mathbb C$. This (counter)example comes from considering the way countability is used in the proof of the result you mention.